# az aks update-credentials - How to ignore Resource Not Found errors

Tags: kubernetes, credentials, azure-aks, azure-service-principal

When trying to update an `AKS` cluster with new service principal credentials using `az aks update-credentials` command, it is blocked with an error about a Resource not Found (a `Microsoft.OperationalInsights` resource).

Is there a way to run this command while ignoring such resource not found error?

Thanks

Comment: As a workaround, the suggestion to disable monitoring add-on for the cluster helped: 
`az aks disable-addons -a monitoring --resource-group clusterresourcegroup --name clustername` (from here: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1380). However, still it would be helpful to have the capability to ignore Resource Not Found errors.